# Is it possible to get the label of a theme customizer option?

Tags: theme-customizer

I have this code for the customizer to add some select options:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'price1', array('default'=>'95'));
  $wp_customize->add_control( 'price1', array(
    'label' => 'price 1',
    'settings' =>  'price1',
    'section' => 'pricessection',
    'type'     => 'select',
        'choices'  => array(
            'reguler price'  => '95',
            'special price' => '65',
            'other price' => '35',
        ),
) );
```

Now if i use this:

```
echo get_theme_mod( 'price1' );
```

In my theme i will get the value of the selected option.

I want to be able to get the label of the selected option also (not the label of the setting). is it possible? how?

**Or in other words:**
How do i echo the "other price" and how do i echo the "35"?

Comment: Couldn't you just `echo "<h4>Price 1</h4>"`?

Comment: I edited the question, to make sure others understand i mean the label of the chosen option, not the label of the setting.

Answer (score 1):

If the customizer has been bootstrapped (that is, if the `customize_register` action has fired), then you can look at the control itself (assuming you flip your `choices` array, as I think your values should be the keys and vice-versa):

```
$price = $wp_customize->get_setting( 'price1' )->value();
$control = $wp_customize->get_control( 'price1' );
$price_text = $control->choices[ $price ];
```

However, you probably want to obtain the chosen price's text outside even when the customizer isn't bootstrapped. In that case, you should store the choices array separately and then pass it in as the `choices` param but then also reuse it elsewhere. For example:

```
$wpse_250302_default_price_choice = '95';
$wpse_250302_price_choices = array(
    '95' => 'regular price',
    '65' => 'special price',
    '35' => 'other price',
);

add_action( 'customize_register', function( WP_Customize_Manager $wp_customize ) {
    global $wpse_250302_default_price_choice, $wpse_250302_price_choices;

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'price1', array(
        'default' => $wpse_250302_default_price_choice,
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( 'price1', array(
        'label' => 'price 1',
        'settings' => 'price1',
        'section' => 'pricessection',
        'type' => 'select',
        'choices' => $wpse_250302_price_choices,
    ) );
} );

add_action( 'wpse_250302_some_theme_action', function() {
    global $wpse_250302_default_price_choice, $wpse_250302_price_choices;
    $price_value = get_theme_mod( 'price1', $wpse_250302_default_price_choice );
    $price_text = $wpse_250302_price_choices[ $price_value ];
    printf( "<h4>%s: %s</h4>", esc_html( $price_text ), esc_html( $price_value ) );
} );
```